# ASA can ping but not computers

Tags: cisco

I just setup a new ASA 5506-X. From the ASA I can ping outside and inside. However inside computers can't ping outside ip, for example  8.8.8.8. Tracert 8.8.8.8 are all timeout. Here are the configuration:

```
: Hardware:   ASA5506, 4096 MB RAM, CPU Atom C2000 series 1250 MHz, 1 CPU (4 cores)
:
ASA Version 9.8(2) 
!
hostname ciscoasa
enable password $sha512$5000$CQmyTVA8Hnz5EPKvxkmsTQ==$olS735SaLOSZR/N052FWAQ== pbkdf2
names

!
interface GigabitEthernet1/1
 nameif outside
 security-level 0
 ip address dhcp setroute 
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/2
 nameif inside
 security-level 100
 ip address 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.0 
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/3
 shutdown
<--- More --->

 no nameif
 no security-level
 no ip address
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/4
 shutdown
 no nameif
 no security-level
 no ip address
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/5
 shutdown
 no nameif
 no security-level
 no ip address
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/6
 shutdown
 no nameif
 no security-level
 no ip address
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/7
 shutdown
<--- More --->

 no nameif
 no security-level
 no ip address
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/8
 shutdown
 no nameif
 no security-level
 no ip address
!
interface Management1/1
 management-only
 no nameif
 no security-level
 no ip address
!
ftp mode passive
object network obj_any
 subnet 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0
pager lines 24
logging asdm informational
mtu outside 1500
mtu inside 1500
no failover
<--- More --->

no monitor-interface service-module 
icmp unreachable rate-limit 1 burst-size 1
no asdm history enable
arp timeout 14400
no arp permit-nonconnected
arp rate-limit 16384
!
object network obj_any
 nat (any,outside) static interface
!
nat (inside,outside) after-auto source dynamic any interface
route outside 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 192.168.11.254 1
timeout xlate 3:00:00
timeout pat-xlate 0:00:30
timeout conn 1:00:00 half-closed 0:10:00 udp 0:02:00 sctp 0:02:00 icmp 0:00:02
timeout sunrpc 0:10:00 h323 0:05:00 h225 1:00:00 mgcp 0:05:00 mgcp-pat 0:05:00
timeout sip 0:30:00 sip_media 0:02:00 sip-invite 0:03:00 sip-disconnect 0:02:00
timeout sip-provisional-media 0:02:00 uauth 0:05:00 absolute
timeout tcp-proxy-reassembly 0:01:00
timeout floating-conn 0:00:00
timeout conn-holddown 0:00:15
timeout igp stale-route 0:01:10
user-identity default-domain LOCAL
aaa authentication login-history
<--- More --->

http server enable
http 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0 inside
no snmp-server location
no snmp-server contact
service sw-reset-button
crypto ipsec security-association pmtu-aging infinite
crypto ca trustpool policy
telnet timeout 5
ssh stricthostkeycheck
ssh timeout 5
ssh key-exchange group dh-group1-sha1
console timeout 0

dhcpd auto_config outside
!
dhcpd address 192.168.1.5-192.168.1.99 inside
dhcpd dns 8.8.8.8 interface inside
dhcpd enable inside
!
threat-detection basic-threat
threat-detection statistics access-list
no threat-detection statistics tcp-intercept
dynamic-access-policy-record DfltAccessPolicy
!
<--- More --->

class-map inspection_default
 match default-inspection-traffic
!
!
policy-map type inspect dns preset_dns_map
 parameters
  message-length maximum client auto
  message-length maximum 512
  no tcp-inspection
policy-map global_policy
 class inspection_default
  inspect dns preset_dns_map 
  inspect ftp 
  inspect h323 h225 
  inspect h323 ras 
  inspect rsh 
  inspect rtsp 
  inspect esmtp 
  inspect sqlnet 
  inspect skinny  
  inspect sunrpc 
  inspect xdmcp 
  inspect sip  
  inspect netbios 
<--- More --->

  inspect tftp 
  inspect ip-options 
!
service-policy global_policy global
prompt hostname context 
no call-home reporting anonymous
Cryptochecksum:9c2cff01a07174783f08cca102d29eab
: end
[OK]
```

Comment: Is it just ping, or is it any communication outbound? Have you confirmed a proper default gateway on the client PCs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following to your configuration:

```
icmp permit any echo-reply outside
icmp permit any time-exceeded outside
icmp permit any unreachable outside
icmp deny any echo outside
```